# Prove that if $p$ is an odd prime then $1^2+ 2^2+3^2+ \cdots +(p-1)^2=0 \pmod p$ provided $p$ isn't $3$.

Tags: number-theory

I am able to prove that if $p$ is an odd prime then $1+ 2 + 3 + \cdots + (p-1) = 0 \pmod p$ is true but I can't seem to find a way to prove it if each term is squared can someone help me out.

Comment: You could use [this expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) for the the sum.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. How do you prove this for $\sum_{j = 1}^{p-1} j$? Can you perhaps generalize that approach?

Comment: Do you know that $1^2+2^2+\cdots + n^2$ has a nice closedexpression in terms of $n$?

Comment: If $\frac{p}{6} | S$, then $p | 6S.$  If you also know that $p$ is an odd prime $> 3$, then $p$ is relatively prime to $6$.  So $p|6S$ and $p$ is relatively prime to $6$.  Therefore, $p|S$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sums of powers modulo $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333278/sums-of-powers-modulo-p)

Answer (score 2):

We know the sum of first n natural numbers is,
$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 =\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
If we use $n=p-1$ then,
$$\displaystyle 1^2+2^2+\cdots+(p-1)^2 = \dfrac{p(p-1)(2p-1)}{6}$$
Now since $p\ne 3$ then we must have $p=3k\pm 1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. For the case $p=3k+1$ we have,
$$\displaystyle (p-1)(2p-1)=\dfrac{k(6k+1)}{2}$$
If k is even we are done as then $6|(p-1)(2p-1)$ which means,
$$\displaystyle 1^2+2^2+\cdots+(p-1)^2=pm\equiv 0 (\operatorname{mod} p)$$
where $m=\dfrac{(p-1)(2p-1)}{6}$.
But here k cannot be odd as then $p=3k+1$ would be even thus violating the fact that p is a prime. Similar argument for $p=3k-1$ works, can you work that one out?

Comment: Let ${S=1^2+2^2+...+(p-1)^2}$, multiply it by ${2^2}$then series becomes  ${2^2S=2^2+4^2+6^2...(2p-2)^2}$   

 - Splitting left and right half, ${[2^2+4^2+...+(p-1)^2] +[(p+1)^2+(p+3)^2+...+(2p-2)^2]}$,  now taking congruence mod p, ${[2^2+4^2+...+(p-1)^2 + 1^2+3^2+...+(p-2)^2]}$, this is exactly what S is.
 - ${2^2S=S (modp)}$  then ${3S \equiv 0(mod p)}$, now p>3, hence ${S \equiv0 (modp)}$